# Error: 'CompatibilityVersion' does not contain a definition for 'Version_2_2 will not go away

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am following a tutorial on creating a Web API through Microsoft's website.
I came across the following error when running the app:
Error   CS0117  'CompatibilityVersion' does not contain a definition for 'Version_2_2'

I went and check into the startup.cs file and checked to see if I have the correct version and according to the documentation, I do.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
 }
```

Does somebody know what could be going wrong?
One thing to point out.  When I created the project I was asked to create it in ASP.NET Core 2.2.  However, I did not have that option, only 2.1 so I created it in that.

Comment: Actually, you didn't come across this while "running the app", you came across it while compiling the app.  CS0117 is a compiler error.  The compiler is complaining that the type `CompatibilityVersion` does not have a member named `Version_2_2`.  If it's supposed to, then you may have NuGet-ted in the wrong version of something.

Comment: Also, can you try explaining this better: _"When I created the project I was asked to create it in ASP.NET Core 2.2. However, I did not have that option, only 2.1 so I created it in that."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2** is not available in Core 2.1.
See the source of [release 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/CompatibilityVersion.cs#L60). It is only available in [release 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/CompatibilityVersion.cs#L84) or higher.

You need to download the .Net Core [SDK 2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) and [migrate your project from 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) or recreate your project in 2.2 if it is quicker.